# Prevent list of files being printed to console when using retrlines

Tags: python, ftplib

I have the following:

```
filelist=[]
aec.retrlines('NLST', filelist.append)
```

As well as doing what I want it to do, which is create a list of files from an FTP folder called "filelist", this also prints that list of files to the console. But I don't want an endless list of file names cluttering up my console. How do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I don't see a list of file names being printed out when using Python 3.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set the debug level to be higher than 2 (set_debuglevel) it will print file names to your console, it's a feature:

```
if self.debugging > 2:
    print('*retr*', repr(line))
```